# How to use order by in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to order alphabetically by a username field in a foreign key like so

```
friends = Friend.objects.filter(recipient=user, status=1).order_by('owner__username') | Friend.objects.filter(owner=user, status=1).order_by('recipient__username')
```

Comment: Could you please post the two models with the ForeignKey relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? -

```
friends = Friend.objects.filter(Q(owner=user, status=1) | Q(recipient=user, status=1)).order_by('owner__username', 'recipient__username')
```